# How to use Function with primitive return or argument type in Java?

Tags: generics, functional-programming, java-8

In Java 8, there is a feature akin to a function-pointer(`java.util.function.Function`). It is usually used like this: `Function<LookupKey,LookupResult>`, however, there is a problem if the method returns a primitive type. `Function<ArgType,Void.TYPE>` doesn't work, it fails to compile with a very confusing error message("cannot find symbol `Void.TYPE`"). I would rather avoid changing my method to return an `Object` just to pass null as the result.

Comment: The error message is only confusing due to your assumption that the existence of a `static` field `Void.TYPE` has any relevance. Since within a generic type signature, classes, type variables or other generic types are allowed, the compiler says that it didn’t find a *symbol* of that name, which means, there is no class named `Void.TYPE`, no type variable named `Void.TYPE`, and no generic type named `Void.TYPE`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your function should not return a value, consider using `Consumer<T>` instead.

If your function should return an `ìnt` or `long` consider using `ToIntFunction<T>` or `ToLongFunction<T>` which returns primitive types.

If your function should return `boolean`, then use `Predicate<T>`.

And finally, if you need to consume an primitive type but want to return a reference type use `IntFunction<T>` or `LongFunction<T>`.

To complete the list: `IntToLongFunction`, `LongToIntFunction`, `IntUnaryOperator` and `LongUnaryOperator` support primitive types to be consumed and returned.

Comment: I wondered why there is no IntToIntFunction. There is a subtype of `java.util.function.Function` - `java.util.function.UnaryOperator`. So the primitive version is the `java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator` interface.

Comment: Yeah I missed to enumerate the two interfaces `IntUnaryOperator` and `LongUnaryOperator` which I added now. Thanks @VsevolodGolovanov

Answer (score 3):

Use the Consumer interface instead. A procedure that doesn't return anything is not a "function."

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Harmlezz, you should use a `ToIntFunction<T>` or any other of the "*toPrimitiveType*" functions and if your method returns no value, use a `Consumer<T>`.

But for the sake of completion - and out of curiosity what is possible:

As you noticed, there is a `Void` class in java, and you can define a Function returning `Void`:

```
Function<Long,Void> f = i -> {
        System.out.println(i);
        return ???;
    };
```

Of course you can just return `null`, but that would cause nasty NullPointerExceptions, for example this won't work

```
f.apply(123L).toString();
```

You can not create `Void` instances - unless you use reflection :)

So let's create a VOID literal (assuming, it's not forbidden by security settings)

```
static Void VOID;

static {
    try {
        Constructor<Void> vc = Void.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
        vc.setAccessible(true);
        VOID = vc.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error(e);
    }
}
```

Now you just return this literal in your function:

```
Function<Long,Void> f = i -> {
        System.out.println(i);
        return VOID;
    };
```

And the function application would result in a non-null result of type Void

```
System.out.println(f.apply(123L).getClass());
```

prints out:

```
123
class java.lang.Void
```

However, NEVER use that in your code unless you want to demonstrate pointless edge cases ;)